# Breaking a launched process programmatically

Tags: windows, process, visual-studio-debugging

I need to launch a process and then break it immediately so that it can be debugged using Visual Studio.
I wrote this code after searching bits and pieces on the internet. The code is not working. The process gets launched, but it does not break and the calling code keeps waiting infinitely. If I don't launch the process in suspended mode, it runs immediately and exits.

I cannot modify the code of .exe that I am launching. I just have the .exe and symbols file.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    LPWSTR commandLine;
    int commandLength;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: Launcher <commandline>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    commandLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, NULL, 0);
    commandLine = new WCHAR[commandLength];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, commandLine, commandLength);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, commandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        cout << "CreateProcess failed (" << GetLastError() << ")." << endl;
        delete[] commandLine;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << pi.dwProcessId << " " << pi.dwThreadId << endl;

    delete[] commandLine;

    DebugBreakProcess(pi.hProcess);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: This is the code after the suggestion by tyson.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    LPWSTR commandLine;
    int commandLength;
    HANDLE processHandle;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: Launcher <commandline>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    commandLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, NULL, 0);
    commandLine = new WCHAR[commandLength];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, commandLine, commandLength);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, commandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        cout << "CreateProcess failed (" << GetLastError() << ")." << endl;
        delete[] commandLine;
        return 1;
    }

    delete[] commandLine;

    processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pi.dwProcessId);
    if (processHandle == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Could not obtain handle (" << GetLastError() << ")." << endl;
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        return 2;
    }

    DebugActiveProcess(pi.dwProcessId);

    //ResumeThread(pi.hThread);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about this issue? Could you get useful information from IInspectable's suggestion? Actually I agree with his suggestion, launch the debugger automatically would be a better workaround.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: revised instructions based on updated code.

I see three things that will help. First, you have to obtain a handle to the process with correct access. The handle returned by CreateProcess does not have correct access. Close that process handle (`pi.hProcess` and `pi.hThread`) and call `OpenProcess` requesting `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`. Keep in mind this may fail if the user account running the program does not have the required permissions.

Next, make sure you first initiate debugging by calling `DebugActiveProcess` with the process handle obtained above. (This may or may not be required.)

Finally, after your edit, I noticed that you are waiting for the process handle using `WaitForSingleObject`. This has the effect of waiting for the process to terminate. Instead, use `WaitForDebugEvent`.

Comment: I don't know if I did it correctly, but I have edited my question above with the new code. It is still not working. I am tried launching the process with CREATE_SUSPENDED flag as well as DEBUG_PROCESS flag. Both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too hard. The system is already well prepared to launch a debugger for any arbitrary process. You only have to set the [Image File Execution Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mithuns/2010/03/24/image-file-execution-options-ifeo/) appropriately to [launch the debugger automatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx).

For reference, here are the instructions quoted from the MSDN:

> To setup an application to launch the debugger automatically
>
> 1. Start the Registry Editor (regedit).
> 2. In the Registry Editor, open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder.
> 3. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options.
> 4. In the **Image File Execution Options** folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug, such as *myapp.exe*. If you cannot find the application you want to debug:
>
>    a. Right-click the **Image File Execution Options** folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New Key**.
>
>    b. Right-click the new key, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
>
>    c. Edit the key name to the name of your application; *myapp.exe*, in this example.
> 5. Right-click the *myapp.exe* folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New String Value**.
> 6. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
> 7. Change the name to `debugger`.
> 8. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Modify**.
>      The **Edit String** dialog box appears.
> 9. In the **Value data** box, type **vsjitdebugger.exe**.
> 10. Click **OK**.
> 11. From the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.
> 12. The directory containing vsjitdebugger.exe must be in your system path. To add it to the system path, follow these steps:
>
>     a. Open the **Control Panel** in Classic view, and double-click **System**.
>
>     b. Click **Advanced System Settings**.
>
>     c. In **System Properties**, click the **Advanced** tab.
>
>     d. On the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**.
>
>     e. In the **Environment Variables** dialog box, under **System variables**, select **Path**, then click the **Edit** button.
>
>     f. In the **Edit System Variable** dialog box, add the directory to the **Variable value** box. Use a semicolon to separate it from other entries in the list.
>
>     g. Click **OK** to close the **Edit System Variable** dialog box.
>
>     h. Click **OK** to close the **Environment Variables** dialog box.
>
>     i. Click **OK** to close the **System Properties** dialog box.
>
> Now, use any method to start your application. Visual Studio will start and load the application.